# updating streamed data from flask in real time

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to stream yielded values in real time to HTML using flask and JavaScript.I would like to stream and display the values without any delay as soon as they are yielded from flask. However, I am currently not able to get the data displayed on the HTML side.

This is the Python Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/stream_time')
def stream():
    def generate():
        t=time.time()
        yield '{}\n'.format(time)
    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')

app.run
```

The HTML/JS code to display and update the values in real time:

```
<p>This is the current value: <span id="latest_value"></span></p>
<script>
    var latest = document.getElementById('latest_value');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '{{ url_for('stream') }}');
    xhr.send();

    var message = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
    latest.textContent = message;
</script>
```

Currently, I am not getting any values displayed on the page and I would like this to update on the field in real time.What am I doing wrong and how do i fix this?

Comment: do you get any error when you run flask in console ? Do you get any error in JavaScript console in web broweser ?

Comment: do you can see stream when you open it directly in web browser `http://your_domain.com/stream_time`

Comment: I thing it will not work - original version in tutorials yields images MJPEG which browser treads in special way and it can recognize where is end of one frame and update image. Your code yields strings all time and AJAX may treads it as one string and wait for end of this string - not as separated values - but yield never ends send text.  Server may have to send text in normal way and JavaScript may have to run loop which get new text.

Comment: BTW: JavaScript may run asynchronously and after running `send()` it may not wait for response and execute next line before it get response.  You may have to use `xhr.onload = function () {...}` to run code when it get response.

Comment: BTW: when I check JavaScript console in web browser I see error - it seems it has problem with `\n` in `xhr.responseText.split()`. To test code in JavaScript you can use `alert()` or `console.log(text)`  (at least in `Firefox`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript works asynchronously and after running send() it doesn't wait for response and it executes next line before it gets response with text.

To get one response you have to use `xhr.onload` (before `send()`) to define function which `xhr` will run when it gets response

```
 xhr.onload = function () {
    latest.textContent = xhr.responseText;
 }

 xhr.send()
```

---

Minimal working code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<p>This is the current value: <span id="latest_value"></span></p>
<script>
    var latest = document.getElementById('latest_value');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '{{ url_for('stream') }}');

    xhr.onload = function() {
        latest.textContent = xhr.responseText;
    }

    xhr.send();

    /* this lines will give `><` because `xhr.responseText` is still empty */
    /* you can remove these lines */
    console.log(">" + xhr.responseText + "<")
    latest.textContent = ">" + xhr.responseText + "<";

</script>''')

@app.route('/stream_time')
def stream():
    def generate():
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S\n")
        print(current_time)
        yield current_time

    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')

app.run()
```

---

To update periodically text in browser you have to first use `while` loop in generator to send many values.

For test I use also `time.sleep(1)` to send less data

```
    def generate():
        while True:
            current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S\n")
            print(current_time)
            yield current_time
            time.sleep(1)
```

Now in JavaScript you have to use `xhr.onreadystatechange` to assign function which will update text on page when it gets new data from server

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var all_messages = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
    last_message = all_messages.length - 2
    latest.textContent = all_messages[last_message]
}
```

Because `xhr.responseText` ends with `\n` so `split('\n')` creates empty message as last element on list `all_messages` so I use `length - 2` instead of `length - 1`

---

Minimal working code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<p>This is the current value: <span id="latest_value"></span></p>
<script>

    var latest = document.getElementById('latest_value');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '{{ url_for('stream') }}');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var all_lines = xhr.responseText.split('\\n');
        last_line = all_lines.length - 2
        latest.textContent = all_lines[last_line]

        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            /*alert("The End of Stream");*/
            latest.textContent = "The End of Stream"
        }
    }

    xhr.send();

</script>''')

@app.route('/stream_time')
def stream():
    def generate():
        while True:
            current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S\n")
            print(current_time)
            yield current_time
            time.sleep(1)

    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')

app.run()
```

---

**BTW:** because I used `render_template_string(html)` instead of `render_template(filename)` so I had to use `\\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: thanks  alot  @furas, let me try this and get back to you.